# Existence of Gamma function integrals

Tags: real-analysis

For given $x \in \mathbb{R},  $ consider $f(t)=t^{x-1}e^{-t}$.

1. For which values of $x$ does the integral $\int_0^1f(t)dt  $ exist?
2. For which values of $x$ does the Riemann integral $\int_0^1f(t)dt$ exist?
3. For which values of $x$ does the improper integral $\int_0^{\infty}f(t)dt$ exist?

This is the Gamma Function and for 1. it is clear to me that the integral exists for $x>1$. In fact that answer seems true for all three examples, however I do not know how to show that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $1$ and $2$, you can compare $f(t)$ with $t^{x-1}$ since $e^{-t}$ is bounded from above and below on $[0,1]$. Thus the question is, when does $$\int^1_0 t^{x-1} dt$$ exist. You can explicitly calculate this (perhaps improper) integral. For $x = 0$, you get $$\int^1_0 \frac{dt}t =  \ln(t) \bigg\rvert_{t\to 0}^{t=1} = - \lim_{t\to 0^+} \ln(t)  = +\infty. $$ For $x \neq 0$, you have $$\int^1_0 t^{x-1} dt = \left[ \frac{t^x}{x} \right]^{t=1}_{t\to 0} = \frac 1 x \left( 1 - \lim_{t\to 0^+} t^x \right) = \left\{\begin{matrix}+\infty, & x < 0, \\ \frac 1 x, & x > 0.  \end{matrix} \right. $$ Thus the integral converges when $x > 0$ and diverges when $x \le 0$.

For $3$, the answer will be the same as for $1$ and $2$. There is no trouble at $\infty$ since the exponential always decays fast enough to make $$\int^\infty_1 t^{x-1} e^{-t} dt < \infty.$$